# What’s the difference between “concerning” and “regarding”?

Tags: differences, tone

**Is there a notable distinction between “concerning” and “regarding”**, be it in tone alone?

I—a non-native—wondered about this when starting a sentence about the weather:

> Regarding the weather, …
>
> Concerning the weather, …

Four other random usage examples:

- [*An Essay <del>Concerning</del> Regarding Human Understanding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_Concerning_Human_Understanding)
- [*Treaty Between France and Spain <del>Regarding</del> concerning Morocco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_Between_France_and_Spain_Regarding_Morocco)
- [*The Question <del>Concerning</del> Regarding Technology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Question_Concerning_Technology)
- [*Protests <del>regarding</del> concerning the Russo-Georgian War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protests_regarding_the_Russo-Georgian_War)

**Aren’t all those unconditionally interchangeable?**

I imagined the difference might be in context, with *regarding* being used when refering to something voluntarily (regards), while *concerning* used when somebody needs to explain oneself (concern), but I dismissed that as a wild guess with lots of examples diluting this attempt to explain.

Comment: According to Etymonline, *concerning* has the idea of *reference* while *regard* has the idea of *looking*. They're mostly interchangeable in English, but one may be preferred idiomatically at times (e.g. best *regards* when signing off), and not interchangeable at all sometimes (e.g. that problem is rather *concerning*).

Comment: I think 'concerning' carries overtones of 'concern = worrying about a serious problem', and that the word thus connotes more seriousness. But they're highly synonymous.

Comment: Could anybody explain why some of the words are struck through?

Comment: @johnc.j. The list comprises exemplary occurrences of one of the words in question respectively, with the other put in lieu thereof, to underline synonymy.

Comment: @dakab Thanks, now it's clear. In such a case, if I were you, I would use parentheses  and a question mark. For example: "An Essay Concerning (Regarding?) Human Understanding".

Answer (score 8):

This piece  from the ***[grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/concerning/)*** discusses about the usage of "concerning"  and its possible overtones as "a cause of concern", but apart from that I think that it is interchangeable  with "regarding":

> - One complaint against concerning does stand up: The word is also a preposition meaning in reference to or regarding, and the adjectival concerning can cause confusion when readers or listeners initially interpret it as the preposition.
> - For instance, if you hear someone say, “His email was concerning,” you might at first expect something to come after concerning. This complaint isn’t a rock-solid case, though, as many words in English have multiple functions, but it’s a good reason for those inclined against the word to continue avoiding it.

Actually checking with ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20question%20concerning%2C%20a%20question%20regarding%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20question%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20question%20regarding%3B%2Cc0)***,  (*a question concerning vs a question regarding*)  it appears that "concerning" used as a preposition meaning "regarding" is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

Among definitions from Webster’s 3rd International Dictionary, 1967 (paraphrased and compacted):

Concerning - To relate or refer to; To be the business affair of.  )The use of concerning as a synonym for anxiety- or distress-provoking or "as a cause for concern' was considered archaic.)

Instead, to describe something as a cause for worry, one might use the word

Disconcerting -  1. To shake the composure of; 2. Causing a loss of composure or self-possession, disturbing.

Example:  It is unsettling to hear the term “concerning” used so frequently as a descriptive, when the speaker usually means “disconcerting.”

Therefore, "concerning" and "regarding" could reasonably refer to some affair or business matter, while it is perhaps better not to use "concerning" as an adjective or adverb.